# exe-file for QGIS application

Tags: qgis, plugins, interface

I have been creating some QGIS plugins lately and configuring the interface of QGIS the way I like it in a programme. I would now like to hand over the system to other people: Is it possible to create an exe-file or something similar which automatically installs QGIS with the correct settings and plugins on another computer?

Comment: Things like this are mostly possible but might be a lot of work. I don't think a tool to do this simply exists at present. An intermediate point might be a set of steps: 1. install qgis; 2. copy my plugin folder to your plugin folder; 3. copy my settings to your settings. If that works then you might try to wrap everything in a self-extracting exe file that does it, but as I say, not simple.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much ! The plugin folder has already been tested on other computers and works. What would be the best way to transfer the settings? 
And do you think it is possible as a "computer science layman" to create such an exe that carries out the three steps you mentioned one after the other ?

Comment: Your settings are stored in your QGIS user profile, which is in your user profile folder, which you should be able to find out where it is from the "Open Active Profile Folder" entry in the setting/user profiles menu. This also contains user-installed plugins. Many years ago I did make a custom Qgis + bits package using a windows installer builder but that was >10 years ago and none of that works now.

Comment: Maybe this : http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Deploying-Qgis-in-an-organisation-td5187600.html and this : https://qgis.nl/2014/04/22/qgis-in-de-klas-onder-windows/?lang=en could give some idea if these other users and you use a shared network

Comment: Thank you for your help ! @Spacedman Now that I have found the folder with the user settings, how do I transfer it to another computer ? Simply replacing the folder on the other computer is not possible, I have already tried that.